# Caching a list from a service call in android

Tags: android, caching, persistence, retrofit2

I'm using retrofit2 to make a service call. One thing that I display is a list.  I have no problem displaying the list even in a case where I have 242 items.  The problem I have is when I select an item from the list to show in a detailed view, a separate activity.

I get this crash in the log

```
RuntimeException: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 873448 bytes
```

If limited the size of the list to 20 items and I no longer get the crash.

What options do I have for caching this list and not pulling out too many to where I get the crash?  I don't want to cache the whole response, just the list and pull out say 20 at a time.
Also, if I end up loading all of them into the list, won't I run into the same problem?

Comment: I assume you are getting that error because you are transmitting the entire list as a parcelable for the Intent to launch the detailed Activity. If you are selecting a single item from the list for showing in the detailed view, why don't you just send that single item in your `Intent` to launch the detailed Activity rather than the entire list?

Comment: That is exactly what I'm doing. I'm passing a single item.  I think it's trying to store the list from the previous activity because I'm not calling finish()

Comment: Are you saving the list in your `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outBundle)` ?

Comment: I pass the list into a fragment but I don't save it in onSaveInstanceState

Comment: Yes so that is the problem - don't pass the list into the Fragment -  it's not a good candidate for transmitting inside a Parcel

Comment: Oh, okay. I'll find a way around doing that. Thanks!

Comment: What would be the best way to pass a large list from activity to fragment?  I have a presenter in my activity but it seems a waste to create a new presenter for the fragment

Comment: you can convert the whole list as a JSON string usign GSON, pass is to fragment and in fragment deserialize it.